# Lightswitch - Ground too short

Tags: electrical, wiring, motion-sensor

I was wondering what would be the best way to extend the ground cable from this lightswitch box? I am trying to install a motion activated light on another box but this one has both ground wires cut to size to pretty much only fit the grounding screw.

Additionally, would I be correct to assume that I only need one of the two ground cables when connecting it to my switch since they are both essentially grounded together to the same box?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

TLDR: Leave the ground wires where they are!  Let the switch pick up ground via its mounting screws.

### Don't fall for "Spare wire syndrome"

Often, novices see a spliced group of, say, white wires. They only need 1, so they break out one and consider the others to be "spares". This does not work.

It does not work because they are not spares at all.  They are doing *other* important tasks; you just don't know about those tasks because you are a novice to wiring.  That is fine, but don't break stuff.

Likewise, those grounds are already doing important work that requires they remain connected *to each other*, and to the box.

In the case of the neutral (white) wires, you need to keep all the whites together and *add yours also*.

However, in the case of grounds, you have things easier because you are in a metal box.

### On metal boxes, cables *must* go to the box *first*

What you see is correct.  Each cable enters the box, and its ground immediately goes to a ground lug on the metal box.  This assures all cables get ground, and the metal box is grounded too.

### ... But then, switches automatically ground

Since the metal box is grounded, your switch will *automagically* pick up ground via the mounting screws and the metal yoke on the switch.

"That was easy".

### You can't do anything else with those ground wires.

Some advice is to pull the ground wires off the box, and put them in a pigtail with pigtails going back to the box and also to the switch.

First, that is illegal.  To join wires like that, you need at least 6" of free wire length in the box. Those ground wires don't have it, and so they can only connect to those ground screws in the back of the box.

Second, those ground screws accept 2 ground wires *each*.  So if you wanted to add a ground pigtail, you could simply lay it in one of the unused slots under those ground screws.

Comment: Thanks that does make sense, completely forgot about the screw grounding. my only confusion in this case is that I am installing a Lutron MS-OPS2 which has a completely plastic casing. I would like to install it without a neutral if possible since neutral for this switch is optional only.  To make the screw trick work would I have to connect the bare wire and the neutral/green from the Lutron switch together? otherwise the barewire that taps from the screw would lead to nothing. The original installation instructions called for both of them to be connected to the outlet ground.

Comment: @PutPutLit since you have neutral present, *use it* -- future generations will thank you

Comment: What is the advantage of using the neutral wire? Thanks

Comment: @PutPutLit Read the instructions.  You must follow the labeling and instructions NEC 110.3(B).  II suspect it says you must use neutral if it's available.  It will be easier to access anyway.  To get to ground you'll need to out and buy a bare #14 solid wire, which I suspect you do not presently have.

Comment: @PutPutLit -- using the neutral is simply better as it means that the grounding system has one less source of low-level currents on it

Answer (score 0):

Can run short piece of ground wire from switch to ground screws or pigtail ground wires together with one going to ground screw on the box, and one to the switch(4 pieces or less)

Comment: I see where  you're trying to go, but that's unnecessary since metal box, and it's also not all that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I like Ideal brand In-Sure connectors, as you can work with really short wire segments and add proper pigtails. You might try loosening the cable clamp temporarily to see if you get a little more wiggle room on the romex.

[image: Ideal In-Sure]

Comment: Thanks I actually did use these on a previous switch in the past and it worked very well the only problem in this case is that it's so short its very hard to get in there/

Comment: I think I'd be working with a couple of pair of pliers (preferably needlenose). (But seeing Harper's very correct answer, the point is sort of moot here.)